# rviz dows not display model (urdf tutorial)

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just installed ROS lunar on Ubuntu 17.04. I wanted to start with the [urdf tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch) and tried to display the second model (*02-multipleshapes.urdf*) but `rviz` does not display the model. I do see the RobotModel Entry on the left side in the TreeView, the links are also there. But in the 3D view in the center I can only see an 3D axis with not mesh.

[image: image description]

**edit:**

```
rosparam get /robot_description
```

outputs

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n<!-- ===================================================================================\
  \ -->\n<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from /home/secret-path-to-my-workspace/urdf/01-myfirst.urdf\
  \ | -->\n<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                \
  \                 | -->\n<!-- ===================================================================================\
  \ -->\n<robot name=\"myfirst\">\n  <link name=\"base_link\">\n    <visual>\n   \
  \   <geometry>\n        <cylinder length=\"0.6\" radius=\"0.2\"/>\n      </geometry>\n\
  \    </visual>\n    <collision>\n      <geometry>\n        <cylinder length=\"0.6\"\
  \ radius=\"0.2\"/>\n      </geometry>\n    </collision>\n  </link>\n</robot>\n\n
```

which is actually the the same urdf file like in the tutorial (except for the collision part)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272692/rviz-dows-not-display-model-(urdf-tutorial)/) by [Westranger](https://answers.ros.org/users/32203/westranger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 165 on 2017-10-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-10**:
Without an image it's probably going to be hard to help you, so please attach one. I've just given you enough karma to do that.

**Comment by [Westranger](https://answers.ros.org/users/32203/westranger/) on 2017-10-10**:
@gvdhoorn thank you very much, I just added the image

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-10**:
Can you make sure that `robot_description` contains the urdf that you think it does?

A `rosparam get /robot_description` should show that.

**Comment by [Westranger](https://answers.ros.org/users/32203/westranger/) on 2017-10-10**:
yes it does, I updated by post accordingly. I was switsching between the first and the second model form the turoial, both don't work for me. To me it looks like rviz does start but it cant visualize anything

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-20**:
This could be caused by locale settings. See [ros-visualization/rviz#1151](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1151#issuecomment-345687074).

**Comment by [Westranger](https://answers.ros.org/users/32203/westranger/) on 2017-11-20**:
@gvdhoorn my main system locale is in german and the VM where it worked was in english, I'll have a look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit (2019-09-09): according to the latest comments on [ros/urdfdom_headers#45](https://github.com/ros/urdfdom_headers/issues/45) (specifically [this one](https://github.com/ros/urdfdom_headers/issues/45#issuecomment-551877532)), the update to `urdfdom_headers` with the fix for non-US locales should be released for Ubuntu Bionic.

After installing the latest updates for Bionic overriding `LC_NUMERIC` should no longer be necessary.

---

original answer: highlighting @gvdhoorn's previous suggestion (for others that come across this issue) that the issue may be related to locales.

Some rviz users have encountered a similar issue on newer ubuntu/debian versions e.g. ROS Lunar on Ubuntu Artful or ROS Melodic on Ubuntu Bionic (see for example: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1249).

If that's the underlying issue, modifying the following environment variable will fix it:

`export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"`.

---

Originally posted by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) with karma: 621 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5